# Can a Docker container register as a GitLab CI/CD Runner during image creation?

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

For instance, if the Dockerfile has code to register:

```
RUN gitlab-runner register \
  --non-interactive \
  --url "https://gitlab.com/" \
  --registration-token "PROJECT_REGISTRATION_TOKEN" \
  --executor "docker" \
  --docker-image alpine:latest \
  --description "docker-runner" \
  --maintenance-note "Free-form maintainer notes about this runner" \
  --tag-list "docker,aws" \
  --run-untagged="true" \
  --locked="false" \
  --access-level="not_protected"
```

And the registration happens during image creation, will the registration be valid/usable when the container runs?

Comment: Why not try it?

Comment: @HansKilian Apologies. I tried looking for it in my asked questions, didn't see it so assumed I forgot to post it.

Comment: @KamilCuk My concern is that it may work a handful of times but then not work in the future. For instance, I don't know how ip addresses of containers work. If the container's ip address gets reassigned (or something along those lines), maybe the registration might break.